# Stored procedure throwing errors while compiling: Oracle sql developer

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have been working with SQL Server for many years now. But there was a requirement in my current project where I had to convert the procedure written in SQL Server to Oracle (in SQL Developer tool).

But there seems to be a lot of minutes syntax changes which I am unable figure out with the error messages thrown.

Here is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROC_MyPROC
(
  PAGENUMBER IN NUMBER 
, PAGESIZE IN NUMBER 
, SEARCHTERM IN VARCHAR2 
, TOTAL IN NUMBER 
) AS 
BEGIN
  IF(PAGENUMBER=1)  
    THEN
          SELECT COUNT(distinct mastraccnt.T1Column1) INTO TOTAL    
          FROM Table1  mastraccnt  
          JOIN Table2 req on LTRIM(RTRIM(req.T2Column1)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(mastraccnt.T1Column1))
          WHERE LOWER(RTRIM(LTRIM(mastraccnt.T1Column1))||' - '||RTRIM(LTRIM(req.T2Column2))) like 
          '%'||LOWER(SEARCHTERM)||'%';
    END IF;

  SELECT distinct RTRIM(LTRIM(mastraccnt.T1Column1)) as MasterAccountId,
  RTRIM(LTRIM(mastraccnt.T1Column1))||' - '|| RTRIM(LTRIM(req.T2Column2)) as MasterAccountName,
  TOTAL AS TotalRows  
  FROM Table1 mastraccnt 
  JOIN Table2 req on LTRIM(RTRIM(req.T2Column1)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(mastraccnt.T1Column1))  
  WHERE LOWER(RTRIM(LTRIM(mastraccnt.T1Column1))||' - '||RTRIM(LTRIM(req.T2Column2))) like 
  '%'||LOWER(SearchTerm)||'%'   
  ORDER BY MasterAccountName    
  OFFSET PAGESIZE * (PAGENUMBER - 1) ROWS   
  FETCH NEXT PAGESIZE ROWS ONLY; 

END PROC_MyPROC;
```

On compiling this i get these errors, not sure what they mean. Can someone help me what is wrong with my procedure?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your code as follows:

1. Your variable `TOTAL` is an input parameter and it can not be changed. You are trying to change its value using `INTO TOTAL`. which is not allowed in oracle.
2. THE second SELECT statement in your procedure needs an `INTO` clause or need to be part of some cursor. You can not write any SELECT query in the procedure just like that. What is expected out of that `SELECT` query?
3. `LTRIM(RTRIM(REQ.T2COLUMN1))` can be replaced with the `TRIM(REQ.T2COLUMN1)`
4. `OFFSET` value must be a static integer.

I think you need something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROC_MYPROC (
    PAGENUMBER   IN           NUMBER,
    PAGESIZE     IN           NUMBER,
    SEARCHTERM   IN           VARCHAR2,
    TOTAL        IN OUT       NUMBER,
    OUT_RESULT   OUT          SYS_REFCURSOR
) AS
BEGIN
    IF PAGENUMBER = 1 THEN
        SELECT
            COUNT(DISTINCT MASTRACCNT.T1COLUMN1)
        INTO TOTAL
        FROM
            TABLE1 MASTRACCNT
            JOIN TABLE2 REQ ON LTRIM(RTRIM(REQ.T2COLUMN1)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(MASTRACCNT.T1COLUMN1))
        WHERE
            LOWER(RTRIM(LTRIM(MASTRACCNT.T1COLUMN1))
                  || ' - '
                  || RTRIM(LTRIM(REQ.T2COLUMN2))) LIKE '%'
                                                       || LOWER(SEARCHTERM)
                                                       || '%';

    END IF;

    OPEN OUT_RESULT FOR SELECT
                           MASTERACCOUNTID,
                           MASTERACCOUNTNAME,
                           TOTALROWS
                       FROM
                           (
                               SELECT
                                   MASTERACCOUNTID,
                                   MASTERACCOUNTNAME,
                                   TOTALROWS,
                                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                                       ORDER BY
                                           MASTERACCOUNTNAME
                                   ) AS RN
                               FROM
                                   (
                                       SELECT DISTINCT
                                           RTRIM(LTRIM(MASTRACCNT.T1COLUMN1)) AS MASTERACCOUNTID,
                                           RTRIM(LTRIM(MASTRACCNT.T1COLUMN1))
                                           || ' - '
                                           || RTRIM(LTRIM(REQ.T2COLUMN2)) AS MASTERACCOUNTNAME,
                                           TOTAL   AS TOTALROWS
                                       FROM
                                           TABLE1 MASTRACCNT
                                           JOIN TABLE2 REQ ON LTRIM(RTRIM(REQ.T2COLUMN1)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(MASTRACCNT.T1COLUMN1))
                                       WHERE
                                           LOWER(RTRIM(LTRIM(MASTRACCNT.T1COLUMN1))
                                                 || ' - '
                                                 || RTRIM(LTRIM(REQ.T2COLUMN2))) LIKE '%'
                                                                                      || LOWER(SEARCHTERM)
                                                                                      || '%'
                                   )
                           )
                       WHERE
                           RN > PAGESIZE * ( PAGENUMBER - 1 )
                           AND RN <= PAGESIZE * ( PAGENUMBER - 1 ) + PAGESIZE
                       ORDER BY
                           MASTERACCOUNTNAME;

END PROC_MYPROC;
/
```

Comment: thanks a lot , that really save a lot of time for me.

Comment: Can you help me with this as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60953138/unable-to-hit-oracle-stored-proc-using-net-ef2-2-core-repository-pattern