# Unable to hit oracle stored proc using .Net EF(2.2) Core repository pattern

Tags: .net, oracle, entity-framework-core, oracle-sqldeveloper, repository-pattern

> ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

This is the error i get when i am trying to hit a stored procedure(in Oracle) from my API.

I am using Repository pattern with Entity framework.(EF Core 2.2)

This is my call,

```
return FetchWithStoredProcedure("PROC_GETMYPROC",
     new OracleParameter("PARAM1", OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Input) { Value = PageNo },
     new OracleParameter("PARAM2", OracleDbType.Int32,ParameterDirection.Input) { Value = PageSize },
     new OracleParameter("PARAM3", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 30, ParameterDirection.Input) { Value = SearchTerm },
     new OracleParameter("PARAM4", OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.InputOutput) { Value = TotalRows },
     new OracleParameter("PARAM5",OracleDbType.RefCursor, ParameterDirection.Output)
                     ).ToList();
```

This is my FetchWithStoreProcedure method

```
public IEnumerable<T> FetchWithStoredProcedure(string query, params object[] parameters)
{
    return _entities.Set<T>().FromSql(query, parameters);
}
```

And this is the exception thrown.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try like the below

```
      return FetchWithStoredProcedure("BEGIN PROC_GETMYPROC(@PARAM1,@PARAM2,@PARAM3
       ,@PARAM4,@PARAM5); END",
```

Comment: I tried it, but got this error ORA-06550: line 1, column 46:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "@" when expecting one of the following:

   ( ) - + case mod new not null <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable>
   table continue avg count current exists max min prior sql
   stddev sum variance execute multiset the both leading
   trailing forall merge year month day hour minute second
   timezone_hour timezone_minute timezone_region timezone_abbr
   time timestamp interval date
   <a string literal with character set specification>

Comment: post the definition of the oracle procedure